# Prototype Pollution script alert doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, alert, xss

This below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/alrusdi/jquery-plugin-query-object/9e5871fbb531c5e246aac2aaf056b237bc7cc0a6/jquery.query-object.js"></script>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #3498DB;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      font-size: small;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
    
    .show {display: block;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="root"></h1>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    var pages = {
      home: `HOME </br>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">home</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href = "?page=about">about</a>
          <a href = "?page=contact">contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>`,
      about: `ABOUT </br>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">about</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href = "?page=home">home</a>
          <a href = "?page=contact">contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>`,
      contact: `CONATCT </br>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">contact</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href = "?page=home">home</a>
          <a href = "?page=about">about</a>
        </div>
      </div>`
    };
    
    var pl = $.query.get('page');
    // var pl = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("page");
    if (pl == null) {
      document.location.search = "?page=home"
    }

    if(pages[pl] != undefined){
      // $('#root').html(pages[pl])
      document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = pages[pl];
    }else{
      document.location.search = "?page=home"
    }
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

And when I try to do a prototype pollution attack on the above code,
example like this,

`https://exaple.com?page=hol&__proto__[hol]=<img src=x onerror=alert(1)></img>`

it works perfectly and gives an alert popup.

but when I use the script tag it doesn't give me an alert popup,
example like this,

`https://exaple.com?page=hol&__proto__[hol]=<script>alert(1)</script>`

Can anybody help that what's going on?
why the `<img>` tag work but not `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

The version with `<script>alert(1)</script>` is harmless because HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted with `innerHTML` should not execute.

See mdn on [`innerHTML` - Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations).

Comment: is there a way to execute even after that?

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't see what you mean with "after"?

Comment: is there a way to bypass this `innerHTML` safety net, so that we can execute script tag?

Comment: If you *wanted* to execute the injected scripts, you'd have to call `eval` on the contents of the injected `script` tag.

Comment: Yeah got that, thx